# VBA Excel - Function Stuck

Tags: excel, vba

I am new ti VBA and i would like to perform a function as follows i hope someone could help me out

I need to set a macro that starts at Cell A2 when i click my function a dialog box appears which i can enter relevant information into and it inserts into the relevant cells

inserts data into 3 fields (B2, C2, D2)

then selects B3 where i can press my button again to do the same thins again

heres my code so far

```
Dim StartCell As Integer

 Private Sub Cancel_Click()
     Unload GarageDimensions

End Sub

Private Sub LengthBox_Change()

If LengthBox.Value >= 15 Then
    MsgBox "Are you sure? You do realise it is just a garage!"
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
Private Sub Submit_Click()
'This code tells the text entered into the job reference textbox to be inserted _
into the first cell in the job reference column.

StartCell = Cells(1, 2)

Sheets("Data").Activate
If IsBlankStartCell Then


    ActiveCell(1, 1) = JobRef.Text
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

ActiveCell(1, 1) = LengthBox.Value
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

    ActiveCell(1, 1) = ListBox1.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select


    ActiveCell(1, 1) = ListBox1.Value * LengthBox.Value

Else
     Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select

End If


Unload GarageDimensions

End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With ListBox1
    .AddItem "2.2"
    .AddItem "2.8"
    .AddItem "3.4"
End With

     ListBox1.ListIndex = 0

End Sub
```

Thanks for your answers in advance

Adam

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `Private Sub LengthBox_Change()` event. You can set the MAX characters of the TextBox `LengthBox` either in the `Design Mode` or in the `UserForm_Initialize()` event as I have done below.

Also if you hard-code the `Startcell` then every time you run the UserForm the data will start from A2 and if there is any data there, then that will be overwritten. Instead try and find the last available row where you can write.

BTW, is this what you are trying (**UNTESTED**)?

```
Option Explicit

Dim StartCell As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set ws = Sheets("Data")

    With ListBox1
        .AddItem "2.2"
        .AddItem "2.8"
        .AddItem "3.4"
        .ListIndex = 0
    End With

    LengthBox.MaxLength = 14
End Sub

Private Sub Submit_Click()
    With ws
        '~~> Find the first empty row to write
        StartCell = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        .Range("A" & StartCell).Value = Val(Trim(ListBox1.Value)) _
        * Val(Trim(LengthBox.Value))

        .Range("B" & StartCell).Value = JobRef.Text
        .Range("C" & StartCell).Value = LengthBox.Value
        .Range("D" & StartCell).Value = ListBox1.Value
    End With

    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub Cancel_Click()
    Set ws = Nothing
    Unload Me
End Sub
```